# How to show a $3\times3$ matrix has three distinct eigenvalues?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control

Here is a question I heared from others:

Given four distinct positive real numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ and set $$a:=\sqrt{\sum_{1\leq i\leq 4}a_i^2}$$
$A=(x_{i,j})_{1\leq i\leq3,1\leq j\leq4}$ is a $3\times4$-matrix specified by $$ x_{i,j}=a_i\delta_{i,j}+a_j\delta_{4,j}-\frac{1}{a^2}(a_i^2+a_4^2)a_j $$
where $\delta_{i,j}$ is the Kronecker symbol or visually
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}a_1 &0&0&a_4\\ 0&a_2&0&a_4\\0&0&a_3&a_4\end{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{a^2}
\begin{pmatrix} 
a_1(a_1^2+a_4^2) & a_2(a_1^2+a_4^2) & a_3(a_1^2+a_4^2) & a_4(a_1^2+a_4^2)\\
a_1(a_2^2+a_4^2) & a_2(a_2^2+a_4^2) & a_3(a_2^2+a_4^2) & a_4(a_2^2+a_4^2)\\
a_1(a_3^2+a_4^2) & a_2(a_3^2+a_4^2) & a_3(a_3^2+a_4^2) & a_4(a_3^2+a_4^2)\\
\end{pmatrix} $$

**The question is to show that the $3\times3$-matrix $B=AA^T$ admits three distinct eigenvalues**.($A^T$ is the transpose of $A$)

What I am curious about is how many methods can be utilized to show a matrix has different eigenvalues?

As for this question my idea is to calculate the characteristic polynomial $f$ of $B$ along with $f'$ which is a quadratic polynomial via Sagemath and show that neither of roots of $f'$ belongs to $f$. Or equivalently to calculate the resultant $R(f,f')$ of $f$ and $f'$ and show that $R(f,f')$ doesn't vanish for any distinct positive $a_i$'s.

But the difficulties are both ways involve hideous calculation which I don't think I can write down by hand. So I'm wondering if there is a tricky way to get to that point? (e.g. an algebraic-geometry method?)

Comment: Well, the matrix is not as terrible as it looks: $A=A_1-\frac{1}{\lambda}ba^t$ with $A_1$ a $3\times 4$ matrix, $b\in\mathbb R^3$, $a\in\mathbb R^4$ and $\lambda=\|a\|^2$.
Moreover, $A_1a=b$, so $AA^t=A_1A_1^t - \frac{1}{\lambda}bb^t$. And finally
$$A_1A_1^t=\begin{pmatrix}a_1^2+a_4^2&a_4^2&a_4^2\\a_4^2&a_2^2+a_4^2&a_4^2\\a_4^2&a_4^2&a_3^2+a_4^2\end{pmatrix}$$
... so maybe the computation is not that terrible (perhaps, with Gershgorin circle theorem?).

Comment: Let $e_j$ be the $j$-th elementary symmetric function of $a_1^2,a_2^2,a_3^2,a_4^2$.  Then the characteristic polynomial of $a^2 AA^T$ is $x^3 - 2e_2 x^2 + 3 e_1e_3x - 4e_1^2e^4$. Not sure what to do next.

Comment: @Samuele Thx for your advice. And I guess it's the right direction. But I still got trouble showing that the three disks doesn't meet. Actually one knows that the eigenvalues of $AA^t$ must be real positive numbers so all comparisons are put in the set of real numbers. Direct calculation seemingly doesn't work for $AA^t$ so I guess we need an extra similar transform to lower the non-diagonal entries. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: I'm wondering what's the subscipt of the last term?

Comment: Sorry, the constant term is $-4e_1^2 e_4$.

Comment: If I didn't screw up, all the eigenvalues are the same if all the $a_i$s are the same.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: Thanks for clarifying. And yes the eigenvalues will coincide when $a_i$'s coincide. So I think that's why the question gives four distinct $a_i$'s.

Comment: eigenvalues are just squares of the singular values of $A$, and you might find it easier to write $A=U\Sigma V$, with $\Sigma$ diagonal matrix containing the singular values, and $U,V$ unitary.

Comment: @Brendan once you have characteristic polynomial f(x), compute the resultant of f,f' w.r.t. x. It is a determinant, a polynomial in $a_k$, vanishing iff there is a repeated eigenvalue. So one would have to show that all of its real roots come from some $a_k$'s becoming equal to each other.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik  The resultant is a big messy polynomial with an irreducible factor of 68 terms.

Comment: 68 terms is on a low side for those sorts of problems.

Comment: In terms of the symmetric functions, the resultant is
$$108 e_1^3e_3^3 - 36 e_1^2e_2^2e_3^2 - 432e_1e_2^3e_3e_4 + 128e_2^5e_4 + 432e_2^4e_4^2.$$  I'll try some other bases.

Comment: one can try setting up equations making sure that a_k are all different, and check the consistency of the resulting system. Namely, add $t_{ij}(a_i-a_j)=1$ for all i<j.

Comment: is it homogeneous in $a_k$ ? if so, one could dehomogenise by setting $a_4=1$, say.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik : as for the SVD method i'm a little bit comfused. Cause in practice when i wanna know the singular values of a matrix, say $A$, I always calculated the eigenvalues of $A^tA$ at first. But in this question where $A$ is an abstract matirx I don't know how to work with it.

Comment: one way or another, A is homogeneous (entries are homogenous rational functions in a_k of degree 1), thus you may assume e.g. a_4=1 w.l.o.g.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik : I know that setting one of $a_i$'s to be a constant number is fine. But after calculation I find that seemingly doesn't make the question easier.

Comment: another option might be setting a=1

Comment: another approach might be to directly express the discriminant as a sum of squares, and show that these squares have no common real roots.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.0475.pdf

Comment: here https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/62911315.pdf
formulas for such a s.o.s. representations are explicit, one basically takes sum of squares of minors of certain 3x6 matrix, cf. Sect 3 there.

Comment: Up to a factor the resultant $R(f,f')$ represents the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Definition) of $f$.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik  This is exactly the algebraic-geometric type result I want! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Another thing that might be useful:$$\det(AA^tx-I)=\frac1{a^2}\frac d{dx}\left[(a_1^2x-1)(a_2^2x-1)(a_3^2x-1)(a_4^2x-1)\right]$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer on methods applicable here (and elaborate on comments I made). The most promising is to use a surprisingly little-known theorem that says that the discriminant $D$ of a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$, i.e.
$$ D_A=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n} (\lambda_i-\lambda_j)^2,$$
is a sum of squares in the ring $\mathbb{R}[a_{11},a_{12},\dots,a_{nn}]$ (notice that $D_A$ is nonnegative, as all $\lambda_k$ are real).
This has been proved independently by a number of authors, e.g. in a [paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/%28SICI%291097-0312%28199811/12%2951%3A11/12%3C1387%3A%3AAID-CPA6%3E3.0.CO%3B2-0#) by P.Lax.

An explicit formula for such an expression for $n=3$ may be found in Sect. 4 of B.Parlett's
[paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(02)00335-X).

This is a rather surprising result for everyone familiar with the fact that most nonnegative multivariate polynomials are not sums of squares (this topic has history going back to a famous paper by Hilbert from 1888).

Comment: I've computed an actual representation of the discriminant as the sum of squares, and verified that setting them all to zeros implies that equality of some pair of $a_i$. So, the problem is settled.

Comment: I've added an explicit solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an explicit solution found computationally (and then beautified) using the approach referenced by Dima.

Let
$$f(x,y,z,t) := (x-y) (z-t) (xy(z+t) - (x+y)zt),$$
$$g(x,y,z,t) := (x-y) (z-t) (xy(z-t) + (x-y)zt).$$
Then the discriminant in question equals
$$2a^{-8}(7s_1 + s_2),$$
where
$$s_1:= f(a_1^2,a_2^2,a_3^2,a_4^2)^2 + f(a_1^2,a_3^2,a_2^2,a_4^2)^2 + f(a_2^2,a_3^2,a_1^2,a_4^2)^2$$
and
$$s_2:= g(a_1^2,a_2^2,a_3^2,a_4^2)^2 + g(a_1^2,a_3^2,a_2^2,a_4^2)^2 + g(a_2^2,a_3^2,a_1^2,a_4^2)^2 + g(a_3^2,a_2^2,a_1^2,a_4^2)^2 + g(a_1^2,a_1^2,a_3^2,a_4^2)^2 + g(a_3^2,a_1^2,a_2^2,a_4^2)^2.$$
(Btw, it can be verified that both $s_1$ and $s_2$ represent symmetric polynomials in $a_1^2,a_2^2,a_3^2,a_4^2$.)

Now, we see that the discriminant as the sum of squares can be zero only when all these squares are zero. Since $a_i$ are pairwise distinct, we can cancel the first two (linear) factors in $f,g$ and focus on third factors being zero. However, in the ideal generated by these factors, there is a polynomial (I checked the first one in the Grobner basis) that is nonzero for distinct nonzero $a_i$, meaning that all squares cannot be zero at the same time.

So, the discriminant is strictly positive.

**PS.** In fact, $s_2$ alone cannot be zero for pairwise distinct $a_i$.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I got mixed up, but I wrote some partial progress using an idea of @Geoff Robinson in a deleted answer (if I have time I will try to finish this). I keep the old "solution" because it is perhaps interesting in itself.

---

FAKE SOLUTION:
As @Samuele has [commented](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393053/how-to-show-a-3-times3-matrix-has-three-distinct-eigenvalues#comment1003226_393053) we need to show that the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_{1}^2 + a_{4}^2 && a_{4}^2 && a_{4}^2 \\ a_{4}^2 && a_{2}^2 + a_{4}^2 && a_{4}^2 \\ a_{4}^2 && a_{4}^2 && a_{3}^2 + a_{4}^2 \end{pmatrix}$$
has distinct eigenvalues. Scaling the matrix by $a_{4}^2$ we can assume that $a_{4} = 1$. Now, substituting $b_i = a_{i}^2 + 1, i = 1, 2, 3$ and subtracting the identity matrix we need to show that
$$\begin{pmatrix} b_1 && 1 && 1 \\ 1 && b_2 && 1 \\ 1 && 1 && b_3 \end{pmatrix}$$
has distinct eigenvalues for all distinct real numbers $b_1, b_2, b_3$. The characteristic polynomial is
$$(x + b_1)(x + b_2)(x + b_3) - (x + b_1) - (x + b_2) - (x + b_3) + 2$$
Notice that by translating the $b_i$ by a constant we can assume without loss of generality that 0 is an eigenvalue, that is
$$b_1 b_2 b_3 - b_1 - b_2 - b_3 + 2 = 0$$
This means that the characteristic polynomial is
$$x \left( x^2 + (b_1 + b_2 + b_3) x + (b_1 b_2 + b_1 b_3 + b_2 b_3 - 3) \right)$$
If 0 is a root of the quadratic factor, then $b_1 b_2 + b_1 b_3 + b_2 b_3 - 3 = 0$. Therefore, we have
$$(x + b_1)(x + b_2)(x + b_3) = x^3 + (b_1 + b_2 + b_3) x^2 + 3 x + (b_1 + b_2 + b_3 - 2)$$
However, the discriminant of this polynomial is a polynomial of degree 4 in $b_1 + b_2 + b_3$, which Wolfram Alpha says is always non-positive, and therefore the polynomial never has 3 distinct real roots which is a contradiction.

(Explicitly, substituting $e_1 = b_1 + b_2 + b_3$ the polynomial is $- 4 (e_1 - 3)^2 \left( (e_1 + 2)^2 + 2 \right)$, and we see that equality happens exactly when $b_1 = b_2 = b_3 = 1$).

Now, it is sufficient to show that the quadratic
$$x^2 + (b_1 + b_2 + b_3) x + (b_1 b_2 + b_1 b_3 + b_2 b_3 - 2)$$
has distinct roots. If this is not the case, looking at the discriminant we get
$$(b_1 + b_2 + b_3)^2 = 4 \left( b_1 b_2 + b_1 b_3 + b_2 b_3 \right) - 12$$
And now we have
$$(x + b_1) (x + b_2) (x + b_3) = x^3 + (b_1 + b_2 + b_3) x^2 + \left( \frac{(b_1 + b_2 + b_3)^2 + 12}{4} \right) x + (b_1 + b_2 + b_3 - 2) = 0$$
Substituting $u = b_1 + b_2 + b_3$, the discriminant is
$$- \frac{1}{4} (u + 6)^2 ((u - 4)^2 + 8)$$
which is non-positive, and therefore the polynomial never has 3 distinct real roots.

---

PARTIAL PROGRESS:

After our normalization of $a_4 = 1$ and substituting $b_i = a_{i}^2 + 1$ our matrix is
$$A A^t = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 && 1 && 1 \\ 1 && b_2 && 1 \\ 1 && 1 && b_3 \end{pmatrix} - \frac{1}{\lambda} b b^t$$
where
$$b = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{pmatrix}$$
Suppose by contradiction that $A A^t$ did not have distinct eigenvalues. Then there would be an eigenvalue $\mu$ whose eigenspace would be 2-dimensional. Notice that $b b^t$ is a matrix of rank 1, and therefore its kernel is 2-dimensional. This means that there is an vector
$$u = \begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3 \end{pmatrix}$$
in the intersection of the $\mu$ eigenspace of $A A^t$ and the kernel of $b b^t$, which means that
$$b_1 u_1 + b_2 u_2 + b_3 u_3 = 0$$
$$b_1 u_1 + u_2 + u_3 = \mu u_1$$
$$u_1 + b_2 u_2 + u_3 = \mu u_2$$
$$u_1 + u_2 + b_3 u_3 = \mu u_3$$
Adding the last three equations and subtracting the first we get that
$$2 (u_1 + u_2 + u_3) = \mu (u_1 + u_2 + u_3)$$
and therefore either $\mu = 2$ or $u_1 + u_2 + u_3 = 0$.

$\textbf{Case i}$: $u_1 + u_2 + u_3 = 0$
In this case we get that
$$(b_i - 1) u_i = \mu u_i$$
for $i = 1, 2, 3$, and so for each $i$ either $u_i = 0$ or $b_i - 1 = \mu$. However, as the $b_i$ are distinct we must have that for at least 2 $i$'s $u_i = 0$. But since the sum of the $u_i$ are 0 we must have that all of the $u_i$'s are zero, which is a contradiction.

$\textbf{Case ii}$: $\mu = 2$
Let the eigenvalues of $A A^t$ be $2, 2, \eta$ for some $\eta \in \mathbb{R}$. We can compute the trace and the determinant of
$$\begin{pmatrix} b_1 && 1 && 1 \\ 1 && b_2 && 1 \\ 1 && 1 && b_3 \end{pmatrix} - \frac{1}{\lambda} b b^t$$
relatively easy using the linearity of trace and the matrix determinant lemma. This gives us two identities on $\eta$, which should be enough to finish.

Comment: In Samuele's comment, $A_1A_1^t$ is just a part of $AA^t$. So I'm wondering how to utilize the fact of $A_1A_1^t$ as shown by you to deduce $AA^t$ has different eigenvalues?

Comment: @LucelliaKassel Yes, I got mixed up between the two matrices.

Answer (score 1):

This question is from this year's Alibaba mathematics competition (qualifying round, which is finished 2 days ago), and here's my solution that could be wrong (I also participated in the competition and this is the solution I submitted). I tried to solve the problem *geometrically* to avoid tons of computations.

---

First, we can deal with $A^{T}A$ instead of $AA^{T}$ since the first matrix's eigenvalues is same as the second eigenvalue's matrix with zero (consider SVD of $A$). The key point is that $A$ can be written as $A = BP$ where
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & 0 & 0 & a_4 \\ 0 & a_2 & 0 & a_4 \\ 0 & 0 & a_3 & a_4 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
P = I_3 - \mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^{T}, \mathbf{v} = \frac{1}{a}(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4)^{T}. 
$$
Especially, the matrix $P$ is an orthogonal projection matrix that project a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ to the subspace of vectors that are perpendicular to $\mathbf{v}$. It satisfies $P^{T} = P^{2} = P$.

To show that the eigenvalues are distinct, we will show that each eigenspace (for nonzero eigenvalues) has dimension 1. In other words, for a given eigenvalue, there exists a unique eigenvector (up to constant factor) corresponding to the eigenvalue.

First, the above $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $A^{T}A$ correspond to the eigenvalue 0 since $A\mathbf{v} = BP\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$. Since the eigenvectors are orthogonal to each other, the other three eigenvectors are in the image of $P$ (the hyperplane perpendicular to $\mathbf{v}$). If we fix an (nonzero) eigenvalue $\lambda$ and a corresponding eigenvector $\mathbf{w}$, we have $P\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{w}$ and so
$$
A^{T}A\mathbf{w} = PB^{T}BP\mathbf{w} = PB^{T}B\mathbf{w} = \lambda \mathbf{w}.
$$
From this, the vector $B^{T}B\mathbf{w}$ should be written as
$$
B^{T}B\mathbf{w} = \lambda \mathbf{w} + \beta \mathbf{v}
$$
for some $\beta$. If we set $\mathbf{w} = (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)^{T}$, then expanding the above equation gives
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a_1^2 & 0 & 0 & a_{1}a_{4} \\ 0 & a_{2}^{2} &  0 & a_{2}a_{4} \\ 0 & 0& a_{3}^{2} & a_{3}a_{4} \\ a_{1}a_{4} & a_{2}a_{4} & a_{3}a_{4} & 3a_{4}^{2} \end{pmatrix}\mathbf{w} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{1}^{2}x_{1} + a_{1}a_{4}x_{4} \\ a_{2}^{2}x_{2} + a_{2}a_{4}x_{4} \\ a_{3}^{2}x_{3} + a_{3}a_{4}x_{4} \\ a_{4}(a_{1}x_{1} + a_{2}x_{2} + a_{3}x_{3} + 3a_{4}x_{4})\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{1}^{2}x_{1} + a_{1}a_{4}x_{4} \\ a_{2}^{2}x_{2} + a_{2}a_{4}x_{4} \\ a_{3}^{2}x_{3} + a_{3}a_{4}x_{4} \\ 2a_{4}^{2}x_{4}\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda x_1 + \beta' a_1 \\ \lambda x_2 + \beta' a_2 \\ \lambda x_3 + \beta' a_3 \\ \lambda x_4 + \beta' a_4\end{pmatrix}, \quad \beta' = \frac{\beta}{a}
$$
Here we used $\langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w} \rangle = a_{1}x_{1} + \cdots + a_{4}x_{4} = 0$ for the second equality. From this, we can show that $x_{4}$ should be nonzero (here's the point that distinctiveness of $a_i$'s are used), so we can assume that $x_4 = 1$ and the other components $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are uniquely determined. This proves our claim that each eigenspace has dimension 1, i.e. the eigenvalues are distinct.